# How to retrieve the value of the DNS in Route53 using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53

I have a DNS created in AWS Route53 using terraform and now I want to retrieve the value of the DNS (IP Address) which are pointed to that using data source. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see a data source for Route53 records, just a resource for creating the records. If you are creating the records with Terraform, can you not reference the value using that resource?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, but if you absolutely needed to get that information and terraform doesn't providate a data source for it, and you didn't make it and can't import it... then I would use a null resource and run a custom command using the AWS CLI to get that data and parse it. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html

That's not a good way to go IMO, but you asked if it's possible

Comment: thank you for the solution. Yeah,  even I was trying to find some resources, but terraform didn't give any resources for that